# Magento - Difference between validator and validator.validate()

Tags: javascript, php, magento

In the login.phtml, what is the difference between validator and validate - Could someone explain what is the meaning of each of the lines below

```
function onepageLogin(button)
        {
            if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
                button.disabled = true;
                loginForm.submit();
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loginForm.validator` just checks the existence of the object (go on if it exists) and
`loginForm.validator.validate()` calls the function validate() of the object (and if the function returns true, too, then the commands inside the if-clause will be executed).

Comment: Thanks. How can i valid only certain parts of the form, say email, and not others like, say password. Currently my validator working on both email and password.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of the jquery validate() method: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ and here is a specific blog post for magento form validation: http://www.human-element.com/form-validation-the-magento-way/ - Probably you just have to remove the class `required` of your form field password.

Comment: Have tried that. I removed the required-entry class from my password input. However, the final submit button still checks for the password input. I was hoping an explanation of the above rows would clear that.

Comment: Any idea why `button.disabled = true;` is required

Comment: It's not required but it's a good practice to prevent that the button will be pressed more than once.

Comment: I think I've found the file you mean here: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml. The class for the password input field is `required-entry` here. Remove that class.

Comment: @hellocode. Yes i did exactly that. But upon submission, it finally throws an error saying need both login and password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83369/discussion-between-vinu-d-and-hellcode).

Comment: This is the javascript part (client side). If you remove all required- and validate- classes of you password field (it's enough to do it in developer mode of your browser) and submit without filling any field then just the email field should be marked.
Of course the server part will not let you in if the account is password protected... but this happens after submission (and after the javascript validation - which was the question here...).

Comment: Agreed. This is along line of what i want to do. I want to use the existing login/password form and convert it into a simple login form (without checking for password) - Am able to do it till here, but am not able to ensure that the login id entered is stored into database. Apologies if not clear